# Minecraft Modding - Blocks taking the same name as each other

Tags: java, module, minecraft

Hello stackoverflow community. I am having a problem with a mod I am making for minecraft, and for some reason, blocks are taking the names of eachother.

Main mod class code involving the blocks:

```
public static final Block bloodStone = new BlockBloodStone(160, 0).setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock).setHardness(5F).setResistance(6F).setStepSound(Block.soundStoneFootstep).getIndirectPowerOutput("bloodStone");
/* Conflict 1: */ public static final Block darkStone = new BlockDarkStone(161, 0).setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock).setHardness(5F).setResistance(6F).setStepSound(Block.soundStoneFootstep);
/* Conflict 1: */public static final Block darkStoneBrick = new BlockDarkStoneBrick(162, 0).setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock).setHardness(5F).setResistance(6F).setStepSound(Block.soundStoneFootstep);
/* Conflict 1: */ public static final Block darkGlowstone = new BlockDarkGlowstone(163, 0).setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock).setHardness(5F).setResistance(6F).setStepSound(Block.soundStoneFootstep).setLightValue(0.8F);
/* Conflict 1: */ public static final Block darkStonePillar = new BlockDarkStonePillar(164).setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock).setHardness(5F).setResistance(6F).setStepSound(Block.soundStoneFootstep);
/* Conflict 1: */ public static final Block darkStoneSmooth = new Block(165, Block.stone.blockMaterial).setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock).setHardness(5F).setResistance(6F).setStepSound(Block.soundStoneFootstep).getIndirectPowerOutput("darkStoneTop");
/* Conflict 1: */ public static final Block darkLog = new BlockDarkLog(166).setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock).setHardness(5F).setResistance(6F).setStepSound(Block.soundStoneFootstep);
public static final Block darkWood = new Block(167, Block.wood.blockMaterial).setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock).setHardness(5F).setResistance(6F).setStepSound(Block.soundStoneFootstep).getIndirectPowerOutput("darkWood");
/* Conflict 1: */ public static final Block darkWoodFence = new BlockFence(168, "darkWood", Block.fence.blockMaterial).setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabDecorations);
/* Conflict 2: */ public static final Block darkGrass = new BlockDarkGrass(169, 0).setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock).setHardness(1F).setResistance(2F).setStepSound(Block.soundGrassFootstep).getIndirectPowerOutput("darkStoneTop");
public static final Block darkDirt = new Block(170, Block.dirt.blockMaterial).setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock).setHardness(1F).setResistance(2F).setStepSound(Block.soundGrassFootstep).getIndirectPowerOutput("darkDirt");
```

---

```
ModLoader.addName(bloodStone, "\u00a74Bloodstone");
/* Conflict 1 */ ModLoader.addName(darkStone, "\u00a78Darkstone");
/* Conflict 1 */ ModLoader.addName(darkStoneBrick, "\u00a78Dark StoneBrick");
/* Conflict 1 */ ModLoader.addName(darkGlowstone, "\u00a78Dark Glowbrick");
ModLoader.addName(darkStoneChunk, "\u00a78Darkstone Chunk");
ModLoader.addName(darkStoneIngot, "\u00a78Darkstone Brick");
/* Conflict 1 */ ModLoader.addName(darkStonePillar, "\u00a78Darkstone Pillar");
/* Conflict 2 */ ModLoader.addName(darkStoneSmooth, "\u00a78Smooth Darkstone");
/* Conflict 1 */ ModLoader.addName(darkLog, "\u00a78Smooth Dark Log");
ModLoader.addName(darkWood, "\u00a78Darkwood");
/* Conflict 1 */ ModLoader.addName(darkWoodFence, "\u00a78Darkwood Fence");
/* Conflict 2 */ ModLoader.addName(darkGrass, "\u00a78Dark Grass");
ModLoader.addName(darkDirt, "\u00a78Dark Dirt");
```

---

```
ModLoader.registerBlock(bloodStone);
/* Conflict 1 */ ModLoader.registerBlock(darkStone);
/* Conflict 1 */ ModLoader.registerBlock(darkStoneBrick);
/* Conflict 1 */ ModLoader.registerBlock(darkGlowstone);
/* Conflict 2 */ ModLoader.registerBlock(darkStoneSmooth);
/* Conflict 1 */ ModLoader.registerBlock(darkStonePillar);
/* Conflict 1 */ ModLoader.registerBlock(darkLog);
ModLoader.registerBlock(darkWood);
/* Conflict 1 */ ModLoader.registerBlock(darkWoodFence);
/* Conflict 2 */ ModLoader.registerBlock(darkGrass);
ModLoader.registerBlock(darkDirt);
```

---

Two Class Examples for Conflict 1:

```
public class BlockDarkStoneBrick extends Block {

public static Icon[] textures = new Icon[2];

@Override
public void registerIcons(IconRegister par1IconRegister) {

    textures[0] = par1IconRegister.registerIcon("darkStoneBrick");
    textures[1] = par1IconRegister.registerIcon("darkStoneTop");

}

public Icon getBlockTextureFromSideAndMetadata(int i, int j) {

    if (i == 0) return textures[1];
    if (i == 1) return textures[1];
    else
        return textures[0];
}

protected BlockDarkStoneBrick(int par1, int j) {

    super(par1, Material.iron);
    this.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock);
}

public int idDropped(int i, Random random, int j) {

    return mod_DarkCraft.darkStoneBrick.blockID;
}

public int quantityDropped(Random random) {

    return 1;
}
}
```

---

```
public class BlockDarkStone extends Block {

public static Icon[] textures = new Icon[2];

@Override
public void registerIcons(IconRegister par1IconRegister) {

    textures[0] = par1IconRegister.registerIcon("darkStoneSide");
    textures[1] = par1IconRegister.registerIcon("darkStoneTop");

}

public Icon getBlockTextureFromSideAndMetadata(int i, int j) {

    if (i == 0) return textures[1];
    if (i == 1) return textures[1];
    else
        return textures[0];
}

protected BlockDarkStone(int par1, int j) {

    super(par1, Material.iron);
    this.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock);
}

public int idDropped(int i, Random random, int j) {

    return mod_DarkCraft.darkStone.blockID;
}

public int quantityDropped(Random random) {

    return 1;
}
}
```

---

BlockDarkGrass class, and darkStoneSmooth code for Conflict 2:

```
public class BlockDarkGrass extends Block {

public static Icon[] textures = new Icon[3];

@Override
public void registerIcons(IconRegister par1IconRegister) {

    textures[0] = par1IconRegister.registerIcon("darkGrassSide");
    textures[1] = par1IconRegister.registerIcon("darkGrassTop");
    textures[2] = par1IconRegister.registerIcon("darkDirt");

}

public Icon getBlockTextureFromSideAndMetadata(int i, int j) {

    if (i == 0) return textures[2];
    if (i == 1) return textures[1];
    else
        return textures[0];
}

protected BlockDarkGrass(int par1, int j) {

    super(par1, Material.grass);
    this.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock);
}

public int idDropped(int i, Random random, int j) {

    return mod_DarkCraft.darkDirt.blockID;
}

public int quantityDropped(Random random) {

    return 1;
}
}
```

---

```
public static final Block darkStoneSmooth = new Block(165, Block.stone.blockMaterial).setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock).setHardness(5F).setResistance(6F).setStepSound(Block.soundStoneFootstep).getIndirectPowerOutput("darkStoneTop");
```

---

All of the blocks under conflict one are taking the name of Darkwood Fence
All of the blocks under conflict two are taking the name of Dark Grass

If you can help thank you if not, that's fine. Also sorry if there is a question that's solved or anything, I tried looking, but my internet is horrible. The ones I looked through did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem! I believe I fixed it by using .setUnlocalizedName("")
For example:

```
public static final Block bloodStone = new BlockBloodStone(160, 0)
.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock).setHardness(5F)
.setResistance(6F).setStepSound(Block.soundStoneFootstep)
.getIndirectPowerOutput("bloodStone").setUnlocalizedName("bloodStone");
```